# Proof of global smoothness of the Exponential map (complete surface)

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose S is a regular, connected surface in Euclidean space and $d_{s}$ is the intrinsic metric on S. When (S,d) is complete, we know that for each geodesic $\gamma:J\rightarrow S$ (where J is any interval) there exists a unique geodesic $\eta:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow S$ which is an extension of $\gamma$.

If $p$ is any point of S, it is shown in do Carmo (page 284) that if a sufficiently small $w\in T_{p}S$ is chosen, the geodesic $\gamma$ with initial state $\gamma(0)=p, \gamma'(0)=w$ is well defined at $t=1$. The symbol exp$_{p}(w)$ is made to denote the point $\gamma(1)\in S$. It is then shown (page 285) that exp$_{p}$ can be made into a smooth map on a sufficiently small neighbourhood of $0\in T_{p}S$. This truth depends on the theorem of solutions of systems of ODE's which says that the solution depends smoothly on initial conditions.

By what I wrote above, when S is complete, $p$ is any point and $w$ any tangent vector to S at $p$, the symbol exp$_{p}(w)$ is well defined, but how can we show smoothness of exp$_{p}$ on all of $T_{p}S$? Am I missing something elementary here? We know it is smooth around $0$, but the proof depended on covering $p$ with a chart and applying the theorem from analysis. It seems we cannot argue this way in the general case.

Comment: Show that the set of vectors $v \in T_pS$ for which $\exp_p$ is $C^1$ is both closed and open.

Comment: The simplest proof of smoothness (that I know of) relies on the theory of smooth manifolds: basically, you define the "tangent bundle" $T(S)$ (which is the union of all tangent spaces), and find a relationship between geodesics of a surface and integral curves of a vector field on $T(S)$. Nevertheless, I don't know of any elementary proof without requiring the introduction of manifolds.

Comment: Completeness tells you that $\exp_p$ is defined on all vectors in $T_pM$. It's the definedness that's the issue; smoothness at $v$ is immediate once you know that the map is defined locally there.

Comment: Would anyone be willing to refer me to a proof of this proposition, please? I have not succeeded in finding a proof.